# Is there a way to "listen" for a program's outbound system messages?

Tags: c#, c++, winapi, windows-messages

I'm trying to replicate the behaviour of an automation tool that sends a few system messages to a program with the specified window handle but I'm not sure which messages it's using. Is there a way to listen to a program's outbound system messages? This is for Windows.

My replica is in C# but I'm familiar with C++ as well, and can use 3rd party tools if available (or if there is a niche Win32 API function that does something like this I can finagle a side project together).

Thank you!

Comment: There is not really such a thing as system messages... Are you referring to Windows Messages, like `WM_ACTIVATEAPP`

Comment: If so, look into one of the various ways you can Dll Inject into a process and proxy calls. Or if this is a managed code base, just decompile it I guess.

Comment: Have you precluded the possibility that the application in question doesn't send messages? The standard infrastructure to automate a UI is unsurprisingly called [UI Automation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winauto/entry-uiauto-win32).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'm trying to replicate the behaviour of an automation tool that sends a few system messages to a program with the specified window handle but I'm not sure which messages it's using. Is there a way to listen to a program's outbound system messages?

If the automation tool is using window messages, you can use monitoring tools like Spy++, Winsight, etc to view them in real time.

Or, you can simply hook the messages of the target window yourself in your own code using the `WH_GETMESSAGE`/`WH_CALLWNDPROC(RET)` hooks of `SetWindowsHookEx()`. You can use `GetWindowThreadProcessId()` to get the owning thread ID of the window, so that you are hooking only that thread and not other threads in the system.